# Prevent server from crashing while interacting with db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to create login form using mongoose. The error has been occurred when I try to find for example an email in my database an it doesn't exist. In this case my app crashed.

Here is my UserSchema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  credit:{
    type: Number,
    default:0
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  telegramId:{
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  inboxMessages: {
    type: Array
  },
  submittedBooks:{
    type: Array
  },
  profilePicture: {
    type: String,
    default: '/'
  }
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

and this is my NodeJS code and query:

```
  UserModel.find({name: 'akbar'}, (err, data) =>{
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else{
      console.log(data[0].password);
    }
  })
```

`UserModel.find({name: 'akbar'}, ....)` cause an error which contains `TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined`. How can I prevent crashing my app?

[image: MongoDB sample]

Comment: find query returns array so not every time you will be getting your zeroth index data... So instead finding with 0th you should map over it... `data.map((res) => { console.log(res.password) })` or you should find with the `email` field instead of `name` and start with **findOne** query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to find an object from the database, there might be 3 scenarios.

> 1. Internal server error (You checked this).
> 2. Empty or null value. (You have not checked it yet).
> 3. Got the desired object. (You print these values)

So to checked scenario 2, use the following code,

```
UserModel.find({name: 'akbar'}, (err, data) =>{
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else if ((!data) || (data.length <= 0)) {
      console.log('No objecct exist');
    } else{
      console.log(data[0].password);
    }
  })
```

Comment: How to prevent catching internal server error! (Scenario 1) ?

Comment: For internal server error, all you can do is just send the error message to the client side. Don't worry, it won't happen in production if the database configuration is ok.

Comment: You mean that it doesn't cause problem in the production? and what do you mean by database configuration?

Comment: If the database configuration is correct, it will crush neither production nor development. Do you still get the error?

Comment: yeah, unfortunately when I try to search 'akbar' in my db, the server stop working! :(

Comment: Does it print the "No object exists" in the console?

Comment: Did you import UserModel?

Comment: Glad to help you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your NodeJS did you import as

```
var userModel = require('place_you_defined_the_model')
```

else, if its just import, like `import('place_you_define_model')`then you should use,

```
user.find({name:'Akbar'})
```

Comment: I did import the following requirements! The problem is that I catch internal server error and my server crashed :)